# JqueryUI Autocomplete : How to display filtered suggestion with condition properly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the `renderItem` of JQueryUI Autocomplete with condition to display or not the filtered suggestion.

Until version 1.8, I used `return false` if the condition was not met and it worked perfectly, but with the new 1.9 version, I got the error : `Uncaught TypeError: Object false has no method 'data'`

I have managed to find a workaround by returning a void object `$('')`, but I am not sure that it is the good way to do that.

Is there someone to explain the right way do avoid the suggestion displaying?

```
$('#myAutocomplete').data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

     if(myCondition)
         return $( "<li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
     else
         return $('');//Cancel the suggestion rendering, return void since 1.9 else just return false
};
```

Inspired by http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Here is a fiddle to play with : http://jsfiddle.net/GF5c4/

Comment: *I am using the renderItem of JQueryUI Autocomplete with condition to display or not the filtered suggestion.* Why? Why not just let the `autocomplete` so its thing and filter the data? The `_renderItem` is used to change the way the list is generated.

Comment: could try removing `return` completely from the `else` ie no `else` at all

Comment: @JoeFletch : The data array used with autocomplete contains data which must only be display if some others conditions (user choices) are met. I won't dynamically reload the list through AJAX call to speed up the UI

Comment: @charlietfl : Your idea return the following error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'data' of undefined", something must be returned

Comment: live and learn I guess. You can possibly do what you need to within the response callback also but if returning `$('')` is not cauing issues no idea what elese to suggest